# what options & time needed to transfer between Gare du Nord & Gare Montparnasse?

Tags: trains, transportation, routes, paris

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Paris Gare du Nord to Gare Montparnasse, by public transport but without lots of walking?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/886/paris-gare-du-nord-to-gare-montparnasse-by-public-transport-but-without-lots-of)

What are options & time needed to transfer on 23/8/2012 bewteen Eurostar/Gare du Nord & Gare Montparnasse ?

Comment: Hi @Steve, welcome to Travel.SE.  Looks like we have this question already - if you're surprised, don't worry, I was too.  I'm going to close it as a duplicate, but if it doesn't answer your question as you'd like, please do flag the question and let us know why and we can reopen it.

Comment: This is actually a better question then the supposed duplicate. The fastest connection between both station actually involves quite some walking.

Comment: The most straightforward and fastest option is to take the Metro number 4, direction "Porte d'Orléans". Get out at "Montparnasse-Bienvenüe". This takes you +- half an hour. To be on the safe side, allow at least one hour between the arrival at Gare du Nord and the departure at Montparnasse.

Comment: @Andra The answers cover all the options, including the direct metro line which is mentioned in the question. There's a link to the [travel planner](http://www.ratp.fr/en/) in the tag wiki as well. I don't see any point in reopening this question, it is really a duplicate.