# Travel from Paris Gare Montparnasse to Gare du Nord

Tags: transit, paris

I am travelling from Toulouse to Gare Montparnasse, then to Gare du Nord.

I have read [Can I travel from Gare du Nord to Gare Montparnasse? (Paris)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78779/can-i-travel-from-gare-du-nord-to-gare-montparnasse-paris) but how to go in the opposite direction?

Comment: This should be a doddle, you just take the Metro

Comment: Why is this not a duplicate? Do you presume the Metro is one way...?

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it's the same procedure to go back the other way, as covered by the previous answer.

The area which services SNCF trains is slightly different to the area of the metro (on both ends) so you will need to follow the signage. However it is fairly clearly signposted.

You would need to take Metro Line 4 in the direction of Mairie de Montrouge. You would exit at Montparnasse - Bienvenue, and you would follow the signs toward the SNCF area if that's where you are going.

You can plan future journeys on the Paris metro and RER system using the [RATP route planner](http://www.ratp.fr/itineraires/en/ratp/recherche-avancee).

[image: From RATP route planner]